# Como usar tags ASP com StringBuilder

Tags: asp, html-tags, stringbuilder

Pessoal estou usando SringBuilder para montar uma pagina em ASP.NET jpa fiz isso várias vezes sem problemas, mas agora eu preciso montar uma string que tem tas ASP dentro dela, montar não é o problema mas a pagina não funciona.

estou fazendo dessa forma :

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

    sb.AppendLine("<div class=""col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"">")
    sb.AppendLine("<img class=""img-responsive"" src=""imagens/208/1005/Clientes.png""/>")
    sb.AppendLine("<asp:ImageButton ID=""ImageButton1"" runat=""server"" ImageUrl=""~/Imagens/Icon-trash2.png"">")
    sb.AppendLine("</div>")

    comandos.Text = sb.ToString
```

Mas o HTML que ele gera está dando erro (Vide baixo)..

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguem poderia me ajudar com isso...??
Obrigado

Comment: o que seria o erro? o </div> em vermelho?!

Comment: Na verdade não é só isso... perceba que o navegador renderizou uma comando do ASP.Net (asp:ImagemButtoN) e esse comando o navegador não reconhece...

Comment: eu nao entendi muito o problema, mas voce tem tentou usar @ no inicio? 
sb.AppendLine(@"<div